# How to unify large sets of crawled items from e-commerce website?

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, e-commerce, text-mining

I am building a new website where data is imported/crawled from some e-commerce websites.

Each group of items is called a product which has a name as a parent of all grouped items.

For Example: `iphone 6s plus 128` and `iphone 7 32` are an item but `iphone 6s` and `iphone 7` are products.

The problem i am facing is the unification of crawled items under one product which refer to it, here is an example:

`Item 1: Fiat 128`

`Item 2: Iphone 6 128`

Both are unified under the same product because both texts contains "128" as a substring.

What i'm trying to acheive is to have the item `iphone 6 128` in it's own group rather than being in the same group with `Fiat 128`, so that we group items more accurately.

**Note:** they are just related because both contains the "128" substring.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your question/problem isn't clear. Perhaps you could restate it?

Comment: @BrianPipa i have restated it with some clarifications, is that enough ?

Comment: Maybe state what you're trying to achieve? "accurate results for unified products" doesn't explain fully what you're trying to do for someone not familiar with the problem. How are Fiat 128 and Iphone 6 128 related? Why are they related just because they have 128 in them?

Comment: @BrianPipa i've stated clearly now what i want to achieve now.

Comment: also show some code you did so we can base our solution on it

Comment: So you're saying they are related because they have 128 in them but they should NOT be related? Can you add some more data items and how they should be grouped? Are you just trying to group on the name of the item? Like all iphones are in the iphone group and since Fiat isn't an iphone it should not be in the iphone group?

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Answer (score 0):

What i have understood from your question is, you want to cluster items based on their type and all items belonging to the same product should be grouped together. So, you should define the list of **products** first. If you don't have a list of products, then it would be difficult to group them with 100% accuracy.

One thing you may consider to do is - cluster items based on their name but only consider the text portion, skip the numeric part. It should give you reasonable clustering.

If you want to go beyond than this, then you can consider NLP techniques. For example, all your items' names are noun phrases, you can find the head word using [Collins Head Finder Rule](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/ModCollinsHeadFinder.html) (using Stanford CoreNLP) and then compare between items.

```
private String getMentionHeadUsingCollinsRule(String phrase) {
    String mentionHead = null;
    Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(phrase);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
        ModCollinsHeadFinder headFinder = new ModCollinsHeadFinder();
        mentionHead = tree.headTerminal(headFinder, tree).toString();
    }
    return mentionHead;
}
```

More advanced: You can use dependency parsing to find the heads of a noun phrase as well but that would be intricate!!